# Problemas en metodo onchange en ASP .NET Core

Tags: javascript

vengo con un pequeño problema al momento de seleccionar en mi dropdownlist ejecuto un script que me calcula la edad, el script va de maravilla y cumple lo solicitado pero realmente el problema es que si lo coloco como método en el metodo onchange al realizar la primera selección no me realiza el calculo , pero si lo selecciono por segunda vez si lo hace, porque motivo se da esto?

Esta es el método ValidarFecha

```
function ValidarFecha() {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#FecNacVal").on("change", function () {
            var now = new Date();
            var birthdate = new Date($("#FecNacVal").val()); // Se Procede a calcular en base a la fecha
            var nowyear = now.getFullYear();
            var birthyear = birthdate.getFullYear();
            var age = nowyear - birthyear + 1;
            $('#EdadVal').val(age);
        });
    });
}
```

Y exactamente el mismo código colocándolo como script al final del formulario y se calcula a la primera selección de fecha

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#FecNacVal").on("change", function () {
            var now = new Date();
            var birthdate = new Date($("#FecNacVal").val()); // Se Procede a calcular en base a la fecha
            var nowyear = now.getFullYear();
            var birthyear = birthdate.getFullYear();
            var age = nowyear - birthyear + 1;
            $('#EdadVal').val(age);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Aquí esta mi input en donde en el método onchange esta declarado ,si escojo la opción del llamado del método.

Fecha de Nacimiento:

Cual es el problema que causa este percance¿?

Comment: Nada de código de C#, ni relacionado a aspnet core.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema básicamente se suscitaba debido a que estaba realizando nuevamente el llamado al método onchange, el código quedaría así, con 2 parámetros que son llenados con las id en el respectivo input

```
function ValidarFecha(idFec, idEdad) {
var ver = $('#' + idFec).val();
console.log(ver);
var now = new Date();
var birthdate = new Date($('#'+ idFec).val()); // Se Procede a calcular en base a la fecha
var nowyear = now.getFullYear();
var birthyear = birthdate.getFullYear();
var age = nowyear - birthyear + 1;
$('#' + idEdad).val(age);
```

}